# Sequelize caching with node-cache-manager

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, caching, sequelize.js

I'm trying to introduce the simplest caching layer in my webapp, all I want to do is cache the results from a few queries for 24 hours as that is how often the DB receieves new data. I'm trying to use node-cache-manager (which looks great) but struggling! I don't think I completely understand how it should be implemented into sequelize. The example is using Mongoose and Mongo by the looks of it:

```
function responder(res) {
    return function respond(err, data) {
        var startTime = moment(res.req._startTime);
        var diff = moment().diff(startTime, 'ms');

        if (err) {
            err.status = 500;
            res.render('error', {error: err});
        } else {
            data.requestTime = diff;
            res.render('users/show', data);
        }
    };
}

function fetchUser(id, cb) {
    var cacheKey = 'user_' + id;

    memoryCache.wrap(cacheKey, function (cacheCb) {
        console.log("Fetching user from slow database");
        User.get(id, cacheCb);
    }, cb);
}

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    fetchUser(req.param('id'), responder(res));
});
```

I'm using MySQL and currently have the example below, but I can see the query hitting the database every time, it does not seem to be persisting or creating the cache...:

```
 function responder(res) {
     return function respond(err, data) {
         var startTime = moment(res.req._startTime);
         var diff = moment().diff(startTime, 'ms');

         if (err) {
             err.status = 500;
             res.json({valuesCount: err});
         } else {
             data.requestTime = diff;
             res.json({valuesCount: res});
         }
     };
 }

function fetchCount(req, cb) {
    var cacheKey = 'allDatabaseRecords',
        table = sequelize.import('extracts');

    memoryCache.wrap(cacheKey, function (cacheCb) {
        console.log("Fetching count from slow database");
        table.count().then(cacheCb);
    }, cb);
}

router.post('/extract-tool/data-filter', function(req, res) {
    var table = sequelize.import('extracts');

    fetchCount(req, responder(res));
});
```

I've tried following the documentation and the example, but this as mentioned, this still hits the DB every time! Any help is MASSIVELY appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work as per the examples given, I had to specifically set and get the key value pair to and from the cache each time.

Now it works fine, structured as below:

```
memoryCache.get(cacheKey, function(err, result) {
    if (result !== undefined){res.json({billingAddress12LastName: result});}
});

memoryCache.wrap(cacheKey, function (cacheCb) {
    console.log("Fetching count from slow database");
    table.count().then(data);
    memoryCache.set(cacheKey, data, {ttl: ttl}, function(err) {
        res.json({valuesCount: data});
    });
}, cb);
```

Still don't understand how the wrap function works and what its for as I'm explicitly setting and getting the cache values now, would appreciate some comments still :).